# How to disable the Slide Menu functionality in iOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm facing some issue with Slide menu in Masterdetail page. I want to disable the functionality in iOS.

In `Android`, I'm able to disable. But, in `iOS` it's not working.

`"IsGestureEnabled="False"` - This Property is working in Android. But not in iOS.

Please help me out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an existing,and you can use **CustomRenderer** . Here is a [workaround](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/171436/#Comment_171436) .However , this workaround seems obsolete because of the update of Xamarin.So we can improve it .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MasterDetailPage), typeof(ExtendedMasterDetailPageRenderer), UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)]
namespace Core.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedMasterDetailPageRenderer : PhoneMasterDetailRenderer
    {
        private MasterDetailPage page;

        public ExtendedMasterDetailPageRenderer ()
        {

        }

         // add following override method
        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
          base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
          ((MasterDetailPage)this.Element).PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
        }
        
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            ((MasterDetailPage)this.Element).PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
        }

        private void HandlePropertyChanged (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == MasterDetailPage.IsGestureEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var panGesture = typeof(PhoneMasterDetailRenderer).GetField ("panGesture", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue (this) as UIPanGestureRecognizer;
                var hasPanGesture = false;

                if (panGesture != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.View.GestureRecognizers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (this.View.GestureRecognizers [i] is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
                        {
                            hasPanGesture = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (((MasterDetailPage)this.Element).IsGestureEnabled)
                    {
                        if (!hasPanGesture)
                        {
                            this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (panGesture);
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    if (hasPanGesture)
                    {
                        this.View.RemoveGestureRecognizer (panGesture);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your **MasterDetailPage**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();

   IsGestureEnabled = false;
}
```

#### Update

Create a `CustomRenderer` of `Page`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(MyPageRenderer), UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
            if (this.NavigationController != null)
            {
                var items = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Items;
                if(items.Length > 0)
                {
                    UIBarButtonItem leftItem = items[0].LeftBarButtonItem;
                    if(this.NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length == 1)
                    {
                        leftItem.Enabled = false;
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its disabling the Slide menu. But when i click on the Hamburger icon, menu is visible. I want to disable that click event in iOS.

Comment: Since you don't want to use the Hamburger Menu .Why did you still use MatserDetailPage?

Comment: Actually, I need that menu bar and toolbar items. In Android, its disabling. But in iOS is not working.

Comment: Check my answer .