# how to enable and disable master detail page menu and gesture?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to enable and disable the bars and gesture of the master detail page (basically the whole menu) so that the user can't navigate when opening a certain page. I tried using a modal page to achieve this but I really need the toolbar menu of the navigation page.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying I am confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the IsGestureEnabled property of the MasterDetailPage to true in the OnAppearing event and false in the OnDisappearing event of each DetailPage, seems giving the expected results.

if `IsGestureEnabled = false;` Property is working in Android. But not in iOS.you could  use **CustomRenderer** ,you could refer to the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822514/10768653)

Comment: Does this disable the bars when I tapped or clicked it?

Answer (score 2):

use [IsGestureEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage.isgestureenabled?view=xamarin-forms)

```
IsGestureEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks how about the menu itself? How can I disable the bars?